# Maven build copy files form a common folder to specific folders

Tags: java, maven, build, maven-2

I have a folder in the file system were I have saved all the Javascripts, css and images and I am building a website with different themes. 
 Therefore in the common folder I have all the common files that have to be copied under the specifc folders at build time.

For example I have the common folder under c:user\common with this structure 

/common
--/css
----myglobal.css
--/img
----common.png
--/js
----mycommonjavascripts.js 
And given a theme like this And a give theme is:
/my-theme
--/css
----mycss.css
--/img
----brand.png
----logo.jpg
--/js
----specific.js
As result I would like to have, if unzipped:
/my-theme
--/css
----myglobal.css
----mycss.css
--/img
----common.png
----brand.png
----logo.jpg
--/js
----specific.js
----mycommonjavascripts.js

Does anybody have an idea how I can achieve a result as shown above with maven?

Comment: Do you want them to be placed in specific locations inside a built jar file?  Or are you using the Maven Assembly plugin to build a sort of *distribution*?  Are you building a war?

Comment: @Alex I interested on both solutions, how can I achieve that?